# Devise: Run code after confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a bunch of code that hands over stuff from a logged in user's guest/lazy registered account to his new account which I run when a new session is created.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    logging_in # this is the method which will run
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

end
```

It works when the user logs in. However when Devise logs a user in after confirmation, the above does not get run. Where should I put the method if I want it to run after a user logs in? whether by logging in or confirmation.

Comment: You can try to redefine this method: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L19

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks nash. Here's how I did it.

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      logging_in # Here it is
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end

  protected

    def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end

    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end

end
```

It needs to be added after `sign_in` because my `logging_in` method uses `current_user`.

Comment: Just a note, if you're extending Devise's controller, you don't have to override `new` and `create` just to call `super`. You can just emit them and that would happen automatically.